# "Product" for used items on a classifieds site?

Tags: schema.org

I have a classified ads website at http://www.gastonia.com.  We are redoing the architecture to be HTML5 compliant as well as heavily use Microdata with Schema.org.

Given that most things there are used, is the [`Product` type](http://schema.org/Product) still the correct choice?

EDIT:

Given the responses so far, Farrukh gave a link with more details. This was on the page:

> The following guidelines apply to product snippets:
>
> When using product markup, the main topic of the page should be about a specific product. Product markup on listing pages is not supported.
>
> The product should be available for purchase directly on the page. We do not support product markup for pages that require a user to visit separate seller's site or contact a seller offline to complete a purchase.
>
> Adult-related products are not supported.
>
> If the product has been reviewed by a single reviewer, the reviewer’s name needs to be a valid name for a Person (e.g. "James Smith") or Team/Organization (e.g. "CNET Reviewers"). For example, "50% off on Black Friday" is not a valid name.

Note the guideline that the object should be available for purchase directly from the page.

Do you think that disqualifies using the `Product` type?

Answer (score 2):

Yes Product uses [Schema](http://Schema.org) which Google now recommends as it is supported by Google, Microsoft and Yahoo, while some older formats are not supported by Bing or Yahoo making schema the most ideal choice.

[Qoute from ***Googles PRODUCT*** Rich Snippets Page](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146750)

> New! schema.org lets you mark up a much wider range of item types on
>   your pages, using a vocabulary that Google, Microsoft, and Yahoo! can
>   all understand. Find out more. (Google still supports your existing
>   rich snippets markup, though.)

You can use [Google's Structured Data tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http://www.overstock.com/Office-Supplies/Office-Star-Professional-Air-Grid-Deluxe-Task-Chair/2605023/product.html&html=) to show how it can be used as well as testing your code before going live

Comment: Just to add , if you are going to sell used items then do use the "condition" property and set it to new or used. Most people get it wrong. The content must be set to one of the properties. http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146750

Answer (score 0):

As long as the end user is able to purchase the item directly through your website without having to contact the original item poster/seller, then the Product vocabulary is absolutely, correct. You'll want to use the *itemCondition* to specify if it's condition as used, refurbished, new, or damaged.

Answer (score 0):

From the Schema.org perspective, using [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product) is appropriate. Schema.org doesn’t restrict that *you* have to offer this product directly on your site, it just has to be *offered* (i.e., by someone, somewhere). And with its [`itemCondition`](http://schema.org/itemCondition) property, you can specify that the product is in [used condition](http://schema.org/UsedCondition):

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <link itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/UsedCondition" />
</article>
```